# Mathematical notation in latex

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

How can I write in latex the $=$ symbol with the word 'def' above it??!

It is because Ive to make use of a definition.

Comment: Like $\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$ ?

Comment: It might be better to ask this here. http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should be migrated to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @b00nheT No, it shouldn't. The question is surely enough a duplicate on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @egreg sure http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125/how-do-i-put-text-over-symbols
but should I have voted *close* instead?

Comment: @b00nheT I first voted to close and answered the question, which I suppose is generally a breach of etiquette, but I imagine this question will be flushed away before long. Simply wanted to help out OP.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Sure. I've done the same as well several times. Mine was just a question to egreg in order to understand what he meant by "No, it shouldn't": what should I have done instead of proposing the migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}` produces your desired $\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$

Answer (score 1):

If AMSMATH package has been loaded, is to use "\overset":

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\overset{\makebox[0pt]  
{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily def}}}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &\myeq b \\
  &=c \\
  &= d.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\sffamily`? I can't understand; it *may* be a stylistic decision based on other parts of the document, otherwise it is completely out of place. And it's wrong anyway: try it in a `\Large` context. By the way, `\mathrel` is redundant, because `\overset` is able to guess that `=` is a relation symbol.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. As I said, I need an update about LaTeX commands :)